# Tkinter destroy root from Toplevel

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, tkinter

I am writing a multi-window GUI  program in tkinter. The code shown below is the layout of the main part of my code. The first window works fine but when I get to the second window by calling `self.next_win`, some things start to go sightly funny.

The main issue is when I go to destroy the GUI: I want there to be a quit button in each window which, when pushed, closes the entire GUI (`root.destroy`). From the first window this works fine, I call the `self.quit` method; but when I get to the second window it doesn't work. I know this is because `master` in the second window is a `Toplevel` widget but I'm not sure how to get around this. I don't see how I can call `root.destroy` from the second window.

How can I fix this? A line in the `SecondWin.quit` method perhaps, or a better code structure which makes the solution trivial (bear in mind I am a beginner so trivialities will have to be explained)? Thanks.

```
class FirstWin:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        ...

    ...

    def next_win(self):
        self.master.withdraw()
        root2 = Toplevel()
        SecondWin(root2)

    def quit(self):
        self.master.destroy()

class SecondWin:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        ...

    ...

    def quit(self):
        self.master.destroy() # What goes in here?

...

def main():
    root = Tk()
    GUI = FirstWin(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is tell SecondWin what the root window is, and it can destroy it.

```
...
    root2 = Toplevel()
    # tell the second window what the master is,
    # and also tell it to be a child of FirstWin.
    SecondWin(self.master, root2)
...

class SecondWin():
    def __init__(self, root, master):
        # root is the root window, master is the parent of this window
        self.root = root
        self.master = master
        <other initialization code here>

    def quit(self):
        self.root.destroy()
```